# Dynamically fed multiple dropdowns only passing last value from form

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-select

I have a recipe database made up of 5 tables, 1 of which is ingredients. I have a form that you enter a numeric value (X) as to how many ingredients are in the recipe, click submit which takes you to another form that has X number of fields and then opposite is a select with the various groups, i.e canned goods, dairy etc.

I have all the fields on the form and the option tags get the data from the DB table but my issue is that when I print_r the 2 arrays I get all the values from the textfields but only the last value from the dropdown lists.

```
//Query groups for list(s)
$ingredient_query = "SELECT DISTINCT groups FROM ingredients";
$ingredient_groups = $pdo->query($ingredient_query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<form id='ingredient_form' action='process_ingredients.php' method='post'>";
   while($x < $ingredients) {
     echo "<label for='ingredient'>Ingredient:</label>";
     echo "<input type='text' name='ingredient[]' placeholder='ingredient'>";
     echo "<label for='ingredient_group'>Groups:</label>";
     echo "<select name='ingredient_group' id='ingredient_group'>";
     echo "<option selected='selected'>Select a value</option>";
                                             
      foreach ($ingredient_groups as $row) {

        $ingredient_group = $row['groups'];    
        echo "<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]' value='$ingredient_group'>$ingredient_group</option>";
                            
     }

     echo "</select><br>";
     $x++;
 }//While loop close
```

[image: Form dynamically generates fields and dropdowns depending on value entered on previous form depending on how many ingredients you have in the recipe]

I am trying to tie 1 ingredient field to 1 group field so that the values can then be saved to the relevant table. What is the best way to do this?

Source:

```
<body>
<div class="ingredient_form_container">
<form id='ingredient_form' action='process_ingredients.php' method='post'>
<label for='ingredient'>Ingredient:</label>
<input type='text' name='ingredient[]' placeholder='ingredient'>
<label for='ingredient_group'>Groups:</label>
<select name='ingredient_group' id='ingredient_group'>
<option selected='selected' disabled>Select a value</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Dry Goods</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Baking Goods</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Dairy</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Fats</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Fruit and Veg</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Herbs/Spice</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Canned Goods</option>
</select><br>
<label for='ingredient'>Ingredient:</label>
<input type='text' name='ingredient[]' placeholder='ingredient'>
<label for='ingredient_group'>Groups:</label>
<select name='ingredient_group' id='ingredient_group'>
<option selected='selected' disabled>Select a value</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Dry Goods</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Baking Goods</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Dairy</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Fats</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Fruit and Veg</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Herbs/Spice</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Canned Goods</option>
</select><br>
<label for='ingredient'>Ingredient:</label>
<input type='text' name='ingredient[]' placeholder='ingredient'>
<label for='ingredient_group'>Groups:</label>
<select name='ingredient_group' id='ingredient_group'>
<option selected='selected' disabled>Select a value</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Dry Goods</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Baking Goods</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Dairy</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Fats</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Fruit and Veg</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Herbs/Spice</option>
<option class='optgroup' name='ingredient_group[]'>Canned Goods</option>
</select><br>        
<input type="submit" name="Submit_num_ingredients" value="Submit Ingredients">
</form>
</div>
```

Print_r()
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Carrot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZb8N.png) => Cream [2] => Butter ) ) Array ( [0] => Fats )

Comment: There is absolutely no reason/benefit to writing the option tag's text as its `value` attribute value.  It is pure markup bloat.  You can safely remove the `value` declaration when it is identical to the option text.  Also, the first option tag is selected by default if no other option is selected.

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with a given `id`. Your generated HTML is not a valid HTML document because you are declaring `ingredient_group` as an `id` inside of a loop.  `for='ingredient'` serves no purpose because there is no element with `id=ingredient`.  `for` attributes only relate to `id` attributes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your generated HTML (source code) as text (not a screen shot).  Since the `foreach()` block is generating identical html every time, there is no need to write it inside your `while()` loop.  Build the select HTML once before the `while()` block, save the HTML to a variable, and echo that variable inside the `while()`.

Comment: Could you expand on 'Build the select HTML once before the while() block, save the HTML to a variable, and echo that variable inside the while().' at all?

Comment: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/2f15b88644d436bd3ac6ab65fcced324/php/php81/c1d63e3f8809235fabb3b7484c7685fc/

Comment: `name='ingredient_group[]'` does absolutely nothing in the option tags.  Only the `name` in the select tag will be respected.